# Django tasks, reminders, notifications

Tags: python, django, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I have a fairly simple web app in Django (Apache, Ubuntu) for keeping some meetings documentation. Meetings have their appointment time stored in database (postgres) in datetime format. Now, I'd like to have a custom reminder module that would enable to user to setup their preferred reminders.

For example:

Meeting will be held at a certain date (let's say 25th of April 2018, 8:00 PM) and user should be able to setup a custom reminder (via SMS for example but the question is not about the sending texts or emails - I got this covered) to be fired up 24h before the time of meeting.

It got me thinking that this requires some kind of a permanent process browsing through the meetings table and checking if now() is the appointment time -24h and if yes then perform the reminder.

I started with rabbitmq and celery but these look a bit complicated at first glance ([here's one of the tutorials I found](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/20/how-to-use-celery-with-django.html)) and looks like it's not designed for what I need.

So, question is - how to setup a permanent process that would check if a set reminder time is now and if yes - perform the reminder task?

---

EDIT: some errors after trying to follow the tutorial in answer. Got stuck at step 3:

```
    (dj2_env) adrian@dev:~$ celery -A dj2 worker -l info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adrian/dj2_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 361, in find_app
    found = sym.app
AttributeError: module 'dj2' has no attribute 'app'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adrian/dj2_env/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/adrian/dj2_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 14, in main
    _main()
  File "/home/adrian/dj2_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 326, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/adrian/dj2_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/home/adrian/dj2_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 279, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/home/adrian/dj2_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 481, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/home/adrian/dj2_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 503, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/home/adrian/dj2_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 366, in find_app
    found = sym.celery
AttributeError: module 'dj2' has no attribute 'celery'
```

Ok, got the above error figured out - it's weird however, as when I ran the worker command from dj2 (project) directory it worked 8|

Comment: The specified tutorial does not contain information about periodic tasks which is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use celery and rabbitmq for this. There is something called periodic tasks in celery which lets you runs tasks given a specific time just like a cron job.

Here is a simple tutorial for [Asynchronous tasks in Celery](https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/)

It gives a good understanding of how celery works. It also includes the configuration, etc.

What you probably need to do is to fire up a task (every 15 mins) which queries the database and checks for meetings within next 24 hours and then notify the user about it. The 4th part of the tutorial shows how you can use periodic tasks.

Answer (score 1):

A Celery periodic task may be the best solution for this, however a simpler alternative may be a Django [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) running from a crontab.

The management command would automatically have access to the Django ORM and could thus perform the database check and send the reminders. You could run it from the crontab such as:

```
# Run the command every 15 minutes
*/15 * * * * python /path/to/manage.py your_command_name
```

Using a management command would also give you the ability to execute the reminder process manually from the command line should you ever have to.

Comment: I was just thinking if this is some sort of "hard-coding" the task? Doesn't seem to be very flexible and/or adjustable by the user, or am I wrong?

Comment: This is a valid solution that is simpler than needing to setup celery or rabbitmq. Less moving pieces if you just setup a crontab job that runs a python script which implements all the logic.